# is jq compatible with jython?

Tags: jq, jython, burp

We currently imported a new class we developed that uses jq to manipulate JSON into our burp's extension code. Upon loading it burp outputs an error of 'no module jq found'.

So after reinstalling everything a few times the possibility of jq not being compatible with jython arose.

Does anybody know about if this is true?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me. https://github.com/mwilliamson/jq.py is not a pure-Python implementation of the filter language used by `jq`; it's a set of bindings for a shared C library.

Comment: jq is a command line tool, though there are python bindings for it. I don't think those bindings are doing anything special so I'm sure it would be fine. Otherwise, you could write out those command line calls through the `os` module or other compatible packages yourself.